# Updating SQL column value with previous row data that said to UPDATE a column to SET previous row value to NULL cells in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have the table as

```
id  value
1   music
2 
3   movie
4   
5
6   book
7
8
```

For the missing rows, and I want to assign the value of previous row like listed below

```
id  value
1   music
2   music
3   movie
4   movie
5   movie
6   book
7   book
8   book
```

How do I write an update statement in SQL Server. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a self joined table

> ```
> CREATE TABLE tab1 (
>   [id] VARCHAR(7),
>   [value] VARCHAR(5)
> );
>
> INSERT INTO tab1
>   ([id], [value])
> VALUES
>   ('1', 'music'),
>   ('2', NULL),
>   ('3', 'movie'),
>   ('4', NULL),
>   ('5', NULL),
>   ('6', 'book'),
>   ('7', NULL),
>   ('8', NULL);
> GO
> ```

> ```
> Update a Set
>     a.[value]  = b.[value] 
> From
>     tab1 As a    
>     Cross Apply (
>         Select Top 1 [value] 
>         From tab1 
>         Where 
>             ( [id] < a.[id] ) 
>             And ( a.[value]  Is Null ) 
>             And ( [value]  Is Not Null ) 
>         Order By [id] Desc
>     ) As b
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> 5 rows affected
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM tab1
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> id | value
> :- | :----
> 1  | music
> 2  | music
> 3  | movie
> 4  | movie
> 5  | movie
> 6  | book 
> 7  | book 
> 8  | book
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=d10f6977b56e9655ff54d0e3e27994ff)*

You can something like this

> ```
> WITH atab1 AS (
> SELECT [id], [value] from tab1 WHERE [id] BETWEEN 1 ANd 5)
> Update a Set
>     a.[value]  = b.[value] 
> From
>     atab1 As a    
>     Cross Apply (
>         Select Top 1 [value] 
>         From tab1 
>         Where 
>             ( [id] < a.[id] ) 
>             And ( a.[value]  Is Null ) 
>             And ( [value]  Is Not Null ) 
>         Order By [id] Desc
>     ) As b
> GO
> ```

3 rows affected

> 

> ```
> SELECT * FROM tab1
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> id | value
> :- | :----
> 1  | music
> 2  | music
> 3  | movie
> 4  | movie
> 5  | movie
> 6  | book 
> 7  | null 
> 8  | null
> ```

> ```
> WITH atab1 AS (
> SELECT [id], [value] from tab1 WHERE [id] BETWEEN 3 ANd 8)
> Update a Set
>     a.[value]  = b.[value] 
> From
>     atab1 As a    
>     Cross Apply (
>         Select Top 1 [value] 
>         From tab1 
>         Where 
>             ( [id] < a.[id] ) 
>             And ( a.[value]  Is Null ) 
>             And ( [value]  Is Not Null ) 
>         Order By [id] Desc
>     ) As b
> GO
> ```

2 rows affected

> 

> ```
> SELECT * FROM tab1
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> id | value
> :- | :----
> 1  | music
> 2  | music
> 3  | movie
> 4  | movie
> 5  | movie
> 6  | book 
> 7  | book 
> 8  | book
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=a1dfe13aa4aa90861c71fdfde5ee507f)*